# Python how to fetch range of key value pairs from dictionary when only two keys are available

Tags: python, json, dictionary

There is dictionary which is in a json format below

```
{
    "values": [{
        "id": "823feb2",
        "message": "Merge pull request #1160",
        "parents": [{
            "id": "822",
            "displayId": "4e8a"
        },
        {
            "id": "8c6",
            "displayId": "8c6"
        }],
        "properties": {
            "jira-key": ["AN-736"]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "822",
        "message": "Merge pull request #1161",
        "parents": [{
            "id": "823efl2",
            "displayId": "4e44a"
        },
        {
            "id": "8c236",
            "displayId": "8c2236"
        }],
        "properties": {
            "jira-key": ["AFN-726"]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "823efl2",
        "message": "Merge pull request #1163",
        "parents": [{
            "id": "4e3t3r2d",
            "displayId": "4e28a"
        },
        {
            "id": "8cwfd6",
            "displayId": "8c4446"
        }],
        "properties": {
            "jira-key": ["AHN-7326"]
        }
    }
    {
        "id": "8782",
        "message": "Merge pull request #1161",
        "parents": [{
            "id": "823ghl2",
            "displayId": "4e44a"
        },
        {
            "id": "8c236",
            "displayId": "8c2236"
        }],
        "properties": {
            "jira-key": ["AFN-726"]
        }
    }]
}
```

Along with this json, separately i have 2 ids(823feb2, 823efl2) in tuple. Now i need to get the range of key value pairs(id[as key] and message[as value]) in a new dict. For this, I need to get all the id and message from the first id until it matches with the last id(in between all id and message should be inserted in the new dict.) rest which lies beyond these id should be ignored.
In short expected result should contain all the keys(823feb2,822,823efl2) except key (8782)

Comment: it should be in python dictionary.

Comment: Ok, understand, but how should the dictionary look like

Comment: Is the desired output like this: `{'823feb2': 'Merge pull request #1160', '822': 'Merge pull request #1161', '823efl2': 'Merge pull request #1163'}`?

Comment: finalDict {823feb2:"Merge pull request #1160", 822:"Merge pull request #1161", 823efl2:"Merge pull request #1163"}

Comment: Try this `a = [x['id'] : x['message'] for x in json['values']]`

Comment: @JosefKorbel Shouldn't it be a dictionary comprehension?, and similar to my answer

Comment: just out of curiosity. Are _you_ sure those are "in range" kind of IDs. To me they look like GIT.-commit-like guid-parts, and `guids` in GIT are just that: `unique identifier` - they are not issued in any ordered fashion. You can have a guid of `abcd04` followed by one of `ff832` followed by `10034`

Comment: @PatrickArtner these json commit ids are in descending format like latest(first dict) are recently commit and below are the old commits in a serial order.

Answer (score 0):

Just a dict comprehension

```
new_dict = {k:v for k, v in old_dict.items() if my_range[0] < k < my_range[1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like from the desired output that you want:

```
print({i['id']:i['message'] for i in json['values']})
```

Output:

```
{'823feb2': 'Merge pull request #1160', '822': 'Merge pull request #1161', '823efl2': 'Merge pull request #1163'}
```

Comment: what does 'i' denote here. I am unable to understand how we are traversing a 'values'.

Comment: @Nikhil `i` is iterating trough your json's `'values'` key and getting the id and message

Comment: its not giving the range which i specified. For example there are ids from 1 to 100 , only 2 and 5 id matches with my tuple, so i need dict from 2, 3, 4, 5 as id and message.

Answer (score 0):

You can get required output using list comprehension -

```
dict_from_json = json.load(open('/path/to/json'))
>>>dict_from_json
{
    "values": [{
        "id": "823feb2",
        "message": "Merge pull request #1160",
        "parents": [{
            "id": "822",
            "displayId": "4e8a"
        },
        {
            "id": "8c6",
            "displayId": "8c6"
        }],
        "properties": {
            "jira-key": ["AN-736"]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "822",
        "message": "Merge pull request #1161",
        "parents": [{
            "id": "823efl2",
            "displayId": "4e44a"
        },
        {
            "id": "8c236",
            "displayId": "8c2236"
        }],
        "properties": {
            "jira-key": ["AFN-726"]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "823efl2",
        "message": "Merge pull request #1163",
        "parents": [{
            "id": "4e3t3r2d",
            "displayId": "4e28a"
        },
        {
            "id": "8cwfd6",
            "displayId": "8c4446"
        }],
        "properties": {
            "jira-key": ["AHN-7326"]
        }
    }]
}

ids = ('823feb2', '823efl2')

output = [{item['id']:item['message']} for item in dict_from_json['values'] if item['id'] in ids]

>>>output
[{'823feb2': 'Merge pull request #1160'},
 {'823efl2': 'Merge pull request #1163'}]
```

Comment: this is returning the same value again and again.
[{'823feb2': 'Merge pull request #1160'}, {'823feb2': 'Merge pull request #1160'}]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have a `dict`

```
In [290]: def get_messages(data, start, end):
     ...:     ret = {}
     ...:     started = False
     ...:     for v in data['values']:
     ...:         if not started:
     ...:             if v['id'] != start:
     ...:                 continue
     ...:             else:
     ...:                 started = True
     ...:
     ...:         ret[v['id']] = v['message']
     ...:
     ...:         if v['id'] == end:
     ...:             break
     ...:
     ...:     return ret
     ...:
```

Testing start to finish

```
In [291]: get_messages(data, '823feb2', '823elf2')
Out[291]:
{'822': 'Merge pull request #1161',
 '823efl2': 'Merge pull request #1163',
 '823feb2': 'Merge pull request #1160'}
```

First to second items

```
In [292]: get_messages(data, '823feb2', '822')
Out[292]: {'822': 'Merge pull request #1161', '823feb2': 'Merge pull request #1160'}
```

Second to third items

```
In [293]: get_messages(data, '822', '823efl2')
Out[293]: {'822': 'Merge pull request #1161', '823efl2': 'Merge pull request #1163'}
```

Last item

```
In [294]: get_messages(data, '823efl2', '823efl2')
Out[294]: {'823efl2': 'Merge pull request #1163'}
```

Non-existent `start` and `end` points

```
In [295]: get_messages(data, None, None)
Out[295]: {}
```